# Gnome-terminal in shell script

Tags: sh, gnome-terminal

I have a shell script like this

```
Comand 1
gnome-terminal  -- ./ a
gnome-terminal  -- ./ b
gnome-terminal  -- ./ c
Comand 2
Comand 3
```

How i can make comand 2 ans comand 3 run after all gnome-terminal comands finish?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `--wait`

```
Comand 1
gnome-terminal --wait  -- ./ a
gnome-terminal --wait  -- ./ b
gnome-terminal --wait  -- ./ c
Comand 2
Comand 3
```